# How can I add an 2d matrix (aXb) into a 4d tensor (e,a,b,2) from a 3d tensor (e,a,b) with tensorflow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, 4d

I have a 3d matrix/tensor, which has the format (1000,250,50) and is an input to my TensorFlow model.

The first number/dimension is the sum of my examples (1000). The second is the length (250), and the width is (50).

Now I want to add an additional "matrix" to each of the thousand training examples with the same shape (250,50), and it should be implemented where I create my functional model because the additional matrix is an output of another neural network.

So I want to get a 4d tensor/matrix where every example consists of two 3d matrices with the size of (250,50).

What I did so far:

```
Input3d= tf.keras.Input(self.input_shape[0], name="Input3d")
Input1dForAddMatrix = tf.keras.Input(self.input_shape[1], name="InputForAdditionalMatrix")

input4d= tf.reshape(Input3d, [batch_size, input3d.shape[1], input3d.shape[2],2])
```

How do I add my additional matrix with input data into this 4d tensor?

I can not do this in advance because the additional matrix is the output of another neural network, which gets another input, and I want to learn them jointly.

Comment: This second additional matrix, is it just one matrix that you want replicated for each example, or are there 1000 different of those too?

Comment: @jdehesa 1000 different ones. they are generated for each training example